# GSP radioGroup inside body of template

Tags: templates, grails, gsp, taglib

Using Grails 2.4.4, I'm trying to add the default g:radioGroup taglib as the body of a template.

```
%{--templates/_wrapper.gsp--}%
<div class="wrapper">
    ${raw(body())}
    %{-- also tried with ${body()} and <%= body() %>--}%
</div>
```

My codec config is untouched: grails.views.default.codec = "html"

```
%{--main.gsp--}%
...
 <g:render template="/templates/wrapper">
    <g:radioGroup name="myGroup" values="[1, 2, 3]" value="1">
        <p><g:message code="${it.label}"/>: ${it.radio}</p>
    </g:radioGroup>
</g:render>
...
```

I inspected the source code of the taglib and it seems that the iterator variable cannot be passed to the body when rendered inside a template. Note that I have no trouble using the taglib outside g:render.